# Mounting NTFS drive in read-write mode

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, ntfs

I have a Seagate hard-disk which is formatted as NTFS in Windows and I use it regularly in Windows. I followed [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/236055/HOW-TO-WRITE-TO-NTFS-DRIVES-ON-A-MAC/) article to install Paragon NTFS for mac and during the trial period I was able to mount my drive in read-write mode perfectly. The same article suggested that Seagate drive users doesn't have to purchase the software and can install it from [Seagate website](https://www.seagate.com/in/en/support/software/paragon/) so that they can mount Seagate drives formatted as NTFS in read-write mode. During installation I got this: [image: System extension blocked] prompt but the installation completed successfully. Now when I try to mount Seagate drives in read-write mode it fails while read-only mode works perfectly fine. Any guide on how could I resolve this issue??

Comment: Anything that [claims compatibility](https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/kb/paragon-driver-supported-operating-systems-and-hardware-006163en/) with "OS X 10.8+" would worry me. You'd have to refer to Seagate as to their precise OS support. It sounds like no-one has updated the utility in years; which may mean it's unsigned & may even be 32-bit. The regular, paid, Paragon NTFS is completely up to date & works well.

Comment: @Tetsujin the download link I have mentioned in my post separates 10.10+ and 10.6 to 10.9. So the last time I can assume the software updated was for 10.10. Currently I am on OS X 10.15.

Comment: Sorry, 10.10 & up - typo… same difference, there have been big changes since.

Comment: For the $20 Paragon NTFS costs, skip a pizza and buy it.